# Check if user exists in specific On Prem AD Security Group in Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-active-directory, azure-security

My organization has On Premises Active Directory and many AD Security groups and also has Azure presence (AD Sync up).  Is it possible for me to write a code and run in Azure that can check if a specific user/logged in user is part of AD Security Group (On Prem)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by setting up Azure AD connect service. Once this is successfully done the synchronization component makes sure that the identity information for your on-premises users and groups is matching the cloud.
Once the sync is done you can query and get the user information one of which is the user's group information.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/

Comment: Aravind - I assume my organization has already setup AD connect and everything is synchronized between On-Prem and Azure.  I'm trying to write a very small piece of code that justo  shows up all the AD Groups a particular user belongs to. I tried to find some sample and I got few, but I'm unable to make it run.  It is giving me permission error, etc.  Could you please point me to right article/code sample?